# Piwik installation using php

Tags: php, iconv, matomo

I have an below error while installing piwik web analytic in to my site

`You need to configure and rebuild PHP with "iconv" support enabled, --with-iconv.`

Please guide me.

Comment: You have to compile PHP with iconv support. See [PHP manual for iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php)

Comment: sorry nikhil it doesnt work....

Comment: Nikhil can you please tell me how to set this error?

Comment: What does not work? Did compilation finished with success? Can you post phpinfo()'s section "Configure Command"? IIRC iconv should be bundled with most versions of PHP nowadays - are you using some non-standard distribution of PHP?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install php5-iconv extension, check etc/php/extensions.ini on "extension=iconv.so" and restart apache.

For openSUSE/Suse:

```
sudo zypper in php5-iconv
```

For FreeBSD:

```
cd /usr/ports/converters/php5-iconv/
sudo make all install clean
```

For Ubuntu it should be part of the main php package.

For RHEL/Fedora/CentOS it should be present in php-common:

```
sudo yum install php-common
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `/etc/php/php.ini` file and uncomment

```
extension=iconv.so
...
[iconv]
iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

Then restart your web server